# assign different derived classes to base class based on condition

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I have a base class and two derived classes:

```
public class base1
{
    public int property1;
}
public class child1 : base1
{
    public int property2;
}
public class child2 : base1
{
    public int property3;
}
```

when I assign `newProp` variable like this:

```
int i = 2;
base1 newProp = (i == 0 ? new child1
{
   property1 = 1,
   property2 = 3
} : null);
```

it works fine and the `newProp` type changes to `child1` class type,
but what I try to do is something like this:

```
int i = 2;
base1 newProp = (i == 0 ? new child1
{
   property1 = 1,
   property2 = 3
} : new child2
{
   property1 = 4,
   property3 = 6
});
```

but I get this error

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `class1` and `class2`
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: i think you should use conventional if else statement rather than using inline operator

Comment: Your code can't be even compiled.

Comment: after fixing syntax rules everything compiles and there was no need for this question.

Comment: The question is relevant for those who still have to work with C# versions prior to C#9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Lasse V. Karlsen, in C# 8.0 and earlier, the type of the first result operator and the second result operator must be the same or there must be an implicit conversion from one type to the other. [(see ?: operator (C# reference))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Explicitly cast one of them to `base1` should do the trick:

```
int i = 2;
base1 newProp = (i == 0
    ? (base1)new child1 
    {
       property1 = 1,
       property2 = 3
    }
    : new child2 
    {
       property1 = 4,
       property3 = 6
    });
```

or

```
int i = 2;
base1 newProp = (i == 0
    ? new child1 
    {
       property1 = 1,
       property2 = 3
    }
    : (base1)new child2 
    {
       property1 = 4,
       property3 = 6
    });
```

Beginning with C# 9.0, the result is target-typed. [(again see ?: operator (C# reference))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)
But only if the target type is known (not using `var`).

In that case you won't get the error on your sample code.

Comment: It's not always the type after the question mark. In C# 8 or earlier, the two branches a and b in `x ? a ? b` must either be the same type, or one of the types must be convertible to the other. In C# 9 it is OK if they're compatible with the target type of the whole expression, meaning in this case `Base` since the target type is `Base` due to the assignment. In C# 8 or earlier, the type of `(i == 2) ? "" : new object()` is `object`, not `string`, so it's not "the type of the element after the ?".

Answer (score 1):

Just help the compiler by casting one of branches to the base class:

```
Base newProp = 
 (i == 0 
? (Base)new Child1 
{
    property1 = 1,
    property2 = 3
} 
: new Child2 
{
   property1 = 4,
   property3 = 6
});
```